# How to make a circular slider in react-native to rotate on both sides?

Tags: react-native, slider, circular-slider

I want to achieve some thing like this
[image: Circular Slider Both sides]

Answer (score 1):

By using the [roundSlider](https://roundsliderui.com/) plugin I have done the POC for your same requirement. This is the jQuery plugin, so I am not sure whether this can be integrated into the react native project. But I believe this will give you some idea or direction towards your requirement. Check the below demo:

## [**`DEMO`**](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/pL6v1r08/)

Screenshot:
[image: roundslider with satisfaction selection smiley]

Comment: Thanks alot I got the idea but I have achieved the same thing by fully customizing react-native-circular-slider this package